# How to use COLLATE Latin1_General_bin in Entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework-6, collate

I have to use COLLATE in entity framework query. How to write SQL query equivalent in Entity Framework as show below code?

**SQL query:**

```
select * from AspNetUsers order by Email COLLATE Latin1_General_bin
```

**Entity Framework:**

```
         using (var db = new testEntities())
            {
                var appUsers = await db.Users.OrderBy(x => x.Email).ToListAsync();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use [Entity Framework's interception hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception).

The first step it to define an interface:

```cs
interface ISortInterceptable
{
    IEnumerable<string> AdaptableSortFieldNames { get; set; }
}
```

Then make your context implement it:

```cs
class TestEntities : DbContext, ISortInterceptable
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<string> AdaptableSortFieldNames { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Next, create a command interceptor:

```cs
class SortCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command,
        DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.DbContexts.First() is ISortInterceptable interceptable
            && interceptable.AdaptableSortFieldNames != null)
        {
            var query = command.CommandText;

            foreach (var fieldName in interceptable.AdaptableSortFieldNames)
            {
                var pattern = $@"(.*\s*ORDER BY\s*.*\.)(\[{fieldName}\])(.*)";
                query = Regex.Replace(query, pattern, "$1$2 COLLATE Latin1_General_bin $3");
            }
            command.CommandText = query;
        }

        base.ReaderExecuting(command, interceptionContext);
    }
}
```

This is where all the magic happens.

- The interceptor first checks if it has to do with a `ISortInterceptable` (maybe this check can be refined by getting *all* `ISortInterceptable`s from `interceptionContext.DbContexts`).
- The command text in the command to be executed is analyzed on any occurence of strings like `ORDER BY [Alias].[fieldName]` where `fieldName` is a variable. This search pattern is in keeping with the pattern EF always follows to generates queries.
- The field name part of the `ORDER BY` clause, which is in the third group (`$2`) of the regex match, is extended by the collation phrase.
- The replacement is repeated for all field names.

Finally, an example of how to use this interceptor:

```cs
DbInterception.Add(new SortCommandInterceptor());
using (var db = new TestEntities())
{
    db.AdaptableSortFieldNames = new[] { "LastName", "Email" };

    var users = db.AspNetUsers
                  .OrderBy(u => u.LastName)
                  .ThenBy(u => U.Email)
                  .ToList();
}
```

As always with string manipulation, one caveat: this works in a couple of my own tests, but I can't guarantee it to be rock solid. For one, the sorting fields should be text fields, of course.

One last note. EF core 3 also offers interception hooks that can be used in a similar way.

Comment: As of EF-core 5 there's a [`Collate` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity#explicit-collation-in-a-query).